# Showing 20,000 records through pagination

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pagination, opencsv

I need to read a CSV file with 20,000 records. I can't put all those records in a list at once. We are not using any database. We are reading the CSV through openCSV framework.
Please tell me some approach so I can read csv part wise part and send the list to Servlet for pagination. This is the sample of code what I have started to implement pagination but its not working.

```
private void viewRecords(List<CSVBean> generated)
    {
        int page = 1;
        int recordsPerPage = 100;
        int offset = (page - 1) * recordsPerPage;
        System.out.println("offset:"+offset);
        System.out.println("recordsPerPage:"+recordsPerPage);

        for(int i= offset;i<recordsPerPage;i++)
        {
            CSVBean csvBean = generated.get(i);
            System.out.println(csvBean.getAttr1());
            System.out.println(csvBean.getAttr2());
            System.out.println(csvBean.getAttr3());
            System.out.println(csvBean.getAttr4());
            System.out.println(csvBean.getAttr5());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please define not working ? getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

Assume there's a variable `totalRecords`, where you store the qty of your records.

So, calculating total pages qty

```
int totalPages = (int) (totalRecords / recordsPerPage);
if (totalRecords % recordsPerPage > 0) {
        totalPages++; // increase totalPages if there's a division remainder
}
```

Send `totalPages` information to the client to represent information like

```
page 1 of 199
```

where `199` is `totalPages`

Now, calculate the first record number:

```
final int firstRecordNumber = (pageNumber - 1) * recordsPerPage + 1;
```

Check, that requested page number is correct:

```
if (firstRecordNumber > totalRecords) {
    // incorrect page number requested, throw exception, process error, etc
}
```

So, now iterate over records, starting from `firstRecordNumber` and print them to the output. Add a new variable, like

```
int printedRecords = 0;
```

and increase it in the loop. Like that:

```
String oneRecord = getRecord(firstRecordNumber);    
while ( (null != oneRecord) && (printedRecords < recordsPerPage) ) {
    printedRecords++;

    // print information to output here

    oneRecord = getNextRecord();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do not use a method which accepts a `List<CSVBean>`. You must use the `CSVReader#readNext()` method to read the CSV lines one by one without storing previous lines is memory. You will have to skip over all the lines which belong to previous pages and then build the response from the appropriate lines. This will of course impose an O(n) overhead, where n is the number of lines belonging to previous pages. There is no way around that using opencsv.

Comment: F.Jameson what if user wants to go back in some different page in pagination that means i don't have any track or pointer to see the CSV data which lies somewhere between in csv how to tackle this problem

Comment: You'll have to re-read the CSV each time, that is the only alternative if you don't want to store the complete file in memory.